# Capturing legacy voicemail - cannot use google voice

Tags: google-apps-script, twilio

is it possible to dial a voicemail line, enter passcode, listen to first voice mail , record the audio to a file, transcribe the audio, capture the metadata (caller id and #) and timestamp,

My wife has to listen to 30-50 voice mails each day at the school where she works.  It is an older phone system and you have to use touch tones (DTMF) - once phone answers you hit *1111#1 to listen to first voice mail, listen, repeat for next voicemail.

I would like to automate this for her and pull these into a google sheet
Timestamp  CallerId  Phone# MP3file transcript

the problem - I have all the pieces working EXCEPT dialing the voicemail line and navigating the tree, capturing the recording(s).  There will be 30-50 recordings each morning and a few throughout the day - I can use a trigger to autodial every hour or so.

I believe Twilio Studio will get me there - but not working.  Ideas, articles, pointers most welcome

(everything else works great - I can hit a twilio endpoint to start the call and if I could get the recording, I can pull the recording, transcript, and metadata into google sheets (or even email /sms it to my self)

Comment: looks like writing a function might work (answering my own question)
https://www.twilio.com/blog/record-studio-voice-calls-functions

Comment: Welcome to [so]. To answer your own question please do it posting an answer. Ref [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Hey @KarlWaldman, did you manage to get any further with this?